# MongoClient.connect doesn't work in a website's onload function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm still learning javascript, and I was trying to write a website that would load information from a MongoDB database into the site. These are the relevant parts of the site:

```
<body onload="intro()">
    <h2 id="rh1"></h2>
    <script src="bgs/roomsbg.js"></script>
</body>
```

Now, the roomsbg.js file looks like this:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

function intro(){
    alert("In intro");
    var roomsy;
    MongoClient.connect("<the connection string>", { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db){
        if (!err){  
            var dbo = db.db("tin_project");
            dbo.collection("Pokoj").find({}).toArray(function(err, result){
                if (err) throw err;
                document.getElementById("rh1").innerHTML = result[0].nazwa_pokoju;
                db.close();
        });}});
}
```

I know that the script itself works, as I've tried it out on its own and it gave me the right data. I also know that the website can reach the intro() function, as it loads the alert. But it doesn't do anything beneath that. I've tried putting the require within the function, and then the alert after that, but it doesn't even load the alert then. I've tried putting an alert within the function in MongoClient.connect, but it also doesn't show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure that ```MongoClient.connect``` is not returning an error to the callback? also are you sure that ```dbo.collection("Pokoj").find({})``` is not returning an empty result? if you scatter alerts around do they ever fire?

Comment: I've ran the intro function on its own, replacing the document.getElementById with console.log, and it returns the result I want it to. While testing, I put one alert over "if(!err)", another above "if(err) throw err", and another one in an "else" under "if (!err)". None of them fired.

Comment: Can you confirm that in the developer tools you don't get the error ```ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `MongoClient' before initialization``` which is what i get when i run you code example. Also i want to make sure that you do actually want to make a client side call to a mongo server. You marked the question as node.js but i don't see any node here. Are you actually trying to write server side code and have accidentally written client side code. It might be a silly question but i have to rule these things out.

Comment: I'm working on this in VS Code, and when I open the page (via the LiveServer extension), I don't get any errors anywhere I could think to check (problems, output, debug console, terminal). I tried debugging the script as well, and it didn't show any problems either. As for the client vs server side, I suppose it is client side? I'm really new to this. 
If this is the error, do you know of any way to fix it?

Comment: I've never used the live server extension. It looks to me like you are getting your client and server side code mixed up. I would suggest writing a simple node api that connects to mongo then call that api from your Web page. There are hundreds of tutorials for how to do that out there. Just Google 'node express api mongo' im sure you will find something.

Comment: I'll... try? Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: @alymoose I think what Damo said was correct, e.g. you're mixing client & server code. Your code appears to call `require("mongodb").MongoClient` in the client side (i.e. the browser). However the MongoDB driver was written for node.js (i.e. it should be called from a node.js server). Unless you include something else, I don't think `require()` will even work client-side.

Comment: @alymoose further, there are two types of Javascript: the client side (which runs in the browser) that you can include in a `<script>` tag, and the server side (which runs in a dedicated node.js process). Both are using slightly different dialect of Javascript. The browser side is used for manipulating client-side presentation (e.g. the DOM), and the server side is used for server processing (e.g. connecting to a database).

Comment: what is this "something else" that I could include? (edit)Actually, I've been trying to work with Ajax (XMLHTTPRequest) but it keeps returning me status 0, so I have to frigging clue what I'm doing wrong. Sorry, I'll... try something else, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing a simple google search for "hello world node mongo express" or "tutorial mongo express" you will get lots of helpful articles to show you how to build a simple node application that uses express to generate HTML  which pulls data from a mongo database.

[This article](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) was near the top of my search results, you could follow along with this and get a quick win. But what I would really recommend is a a course from say [udemy](https://www.udemy.com/) where you can learn how to build a dynamic website using node and express. There are loads of courses and often you get what you pay for but [This course](https://www.udemy.com/mongo-db-with-node-express/) is free, I've not sat it, so i cant vouch for it but you cant argue with free.

To sum up i would say given your question and your misunderstandings i would say that a course of some kind would be beneficial to you, you need to understand the basic concepts and learn some basic ways of doing what you are trying to achieve. Good luck.

Comment: Will look through those. Thanks!